# What role does 어 버리다 play with the verb 되다?

Tags: grammar

Here is the reference phrase :

> 긴 하루가 **되어** 버렸어

where :
되: become 
어 버렸어: do completely

Which is clear in meaning, but i hope can you explain for me this grammatical case.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, 버리다 means 'throw away', while the ending **-어 버리다** is commonly said to denote doing something 'completely'. However, -어 버리다 can give emphasis in a number of ways. One of the meanings is surprise, so:

> 긴 하루가 되어 버렸어

Could mean something like 'It (unexpectedly) became a long day' (we thought things would finish sooner).

[Talk To Me In Korean](http://talktomeinkorean.com/lessons/l9l2/) has a good lesson on this.